# Difference between Generalization and inheritance with suitable example. OOAD

Tags: object-oriented-analysis, ooad

Studying about Generalization and inheritance making me confuse, both gives the same meaning as if something is being inherited..but cant figure out the actual difference.

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/uml/modeling-it-systems/structural-view/generalization-specialization-and-inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generalization/specialization relationship is implemented in object-oriented programming languages with inheritance.

Some Forms of Generalization

1. **Hierarchy:** In the case of hierarchy, the commonalities are organized into a tree structured form. At the root of any subtree are found all the attributes and behavior common to all of the descendents of that root.
2. **Genericity:** In this case, the commonality is expressed with the aid of a parameter. Various specializations are distinguished by what they provide for the parameter. For example, using genericity it is possible to represent the common properties of a "stack" through the generalization of a "stack of anything", where "anything" represents the parameter.
3. **Polymorphism:** Polymorphism captures commonality in algorithms. Polymorphism allows the nested logic (or case statement) to be collapsed to a single case in which the different object types are treated in a uniform manner.
4. **Patterns:** A pattern expresses a general solution (the key components and relationships) to a commonly occurring design problem. The attributes and behavior of the individual components are only partially defined to allow the pattern to be interpreted and applied to a wide range of situations.

Comment: [Read more on Generalization and inheritance](http://www.universalteacherpublications.com/univ/free-asgn/2008/mcs32/page1.htm)

Answer (score 14):

**Generalization** is the term that we use to denote abstraction of common properties into a base class in UML.

When we implement Generalization in a programming language, it is called **Inheritance**.

So, Generalization and Inheritance are same, the terminology just differs depending on the context where it is being used.